# how to remove firefox's Default Dropdown for input html

Tags: html, css

In chrome my input looks like this [image]

and in firefox like this
[image]

how to remove that default firefox dropdown.

Comment: consider using normalize css or reset css

Answer (score 3):

The `-moz-appearance` CSS property is used in Gecko (Firefox) to display an element using platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme.

The `-webkit-appearance` property is used by WebKit-based (e.g., Safari) and Blink-based (e.g., Chrome, Opera) browsers to achieve the same thing. Note that Firefox and Edge also support `-webkit-appearance`, for compatibility reasons.

[Reference from MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

[This example from CSS-Tricks can help you understand more about `appearance` CSS property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```